# connect to a mongodb instance without "--authenticationDatabase admin"

Tags: mongodb

So I got my mongodb instance ready, open for remote connections.

From some reason, I'm unable to connect it with a user/pass **without `--authenticationDatabase admin`** added to the connection string.

When I try to perform the connection with the user/pass alone (without "authenticationDatabase", I get:

```
2015-02-01T16:07:24.818-0500 Error: 18 { ok: 0.0, errmsg: "auth failed", code: 18 } at src/mongo/shell/db.js:1210
exception: login failed
```

Comment: Could you provide the full connection command? It's not clear which database you are connecting to and what other options are.

Answer (score 11):

Thanks @Gianfranco P.

Briefly: If you want to connect to the database without `authenticationDatabase` option you should create user in the same database which you want to connect to.

For example

```
mongodb://demouser:demopass@<host>:<port>/demodb
```

For this URI you should create your `demouser` user in `demodb` database, otherwise you have to provide `authenticationDatabase` option like this

```
mongodb://demouser:demopass@<host>:<port>/demodb?authSource=<authDatabase>
```

Comment: +1 for the mention of `authSource`, documented [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/#urioption.authSource)

Answer (score 10):

This is because the user credentials are stored in the admin database and *not* in the default database where the mongo shell connects to (test).

You can change this with the connection URL:

With the `admin` database:

```
$ mongo localhost/admin --username user -p
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.9
Enter password:
connecting to: localhost/admin
replset:PRIMARY>
```

Without a specific database (`test` by default):

```
$ mongo localhost --username user -p
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.9
Enter password:
connecting to: localhost
2015-04-22T15:34:28.743+0100 Error: 18 { ok: 0.0, errmsg: "auth failed", code: 18 } at src/mongo/shell/db.js:1260
exception: login failed
```

With `--authenticationDatabase`:

```
$ mongo localhost --username user --authenticationDatabase admin -p
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.9
Enter password:
connecting to: localhost
replset:PRIMARY>
```

Note that using `--host` will not assume the database name is the one after the `/` (slash:

```
$ mongo --host localhost/admin --username user -p
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.9
Enter password:
connecting to: localhost/admin:27017/test
2015-04-22T15:37:40.703+0100 starting new replica set monitor for replica set localhost with seeds admin:27017
2015-04-22T15:37:40.703+0100 [ReplicaSetMonitorWatcher] starting
2015-04-22T15:37:40.920+0100 getaddrinfo("admin") failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
2015-04-22T15:37:40.922+0100 warning: No primary detected for set localhost
2015-04-22T15:37:40.922+0100 All nodes for set localhost are down. This has happened for 1 checks in a row. Polling will stop after 29 more failed checks
2015-04-22T15:37:40.923+0100 Error: connect failed to replica set localhost/admin:27017 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:148
exception: connect failed
```

Answer (score 1):

Add authenticationDatabase parameter to the mongo uri.

For example-

```
mongodb+srv://<user_name>:<password>@<host>:<port>/demo?&authenticationDatabase=admin
```