# MongoDB: All commands spit out "not authorized on admin to execute command"

Tags: mongodb

I spun up a mongoDB droplet so that I could have a database connected to my little game. However, complications after complications have arisen.
I am connecting to the droplet through PuTTY and was previously able to invoke "mongo" then type "show dbs" to see all the current databases.

I had been altering the /etc/mongod.conf file to allow remote connecting, and since then - any command that I invoke spits back an error message:

Just through a simple show dbs - I get this.

```
> show dbs
2016-12-28T00:12:26.655+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: listDatabases failed:{
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "not authorized on admin to execute command { listDatabases: 1.0 }",
        "code" : 13
} :
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
Mongo.prototype.getDBs@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:62:1
shellHelper.show@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:761:19
shellHelper@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:651:15
@(shellhelp2):1:1
```

I'm so confused as to why this is and I've been scouring the internet to find anything that could possibly resolve this.

Comment: I experienced a problem similar to this using Kubernetes clusters and the helm chart 'mongodb-replicaset'.  The persistentvolumes had the "old keys", while I was trying to rebuild the cluster with "new keys".

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you are connected to a MongoDB instance that has authorization enabled and when you connected to MongoDB via the shell you didn't specify any credentials.  The MongoDB shell will allow you to connect in this case but any command you type will error out.

Comment: Well in my case i did in fact specify credentials. -u and -p , and yet it still logs me in as "admin". Thus the issue. Running in circles with this.

Comment: Did you define the authentication database when connecting?  i.e. pass the parameter "--authenticationDatabase" when connecting via Mongo shell? I found this discussion which may be of help,  https://stackoverflow.com/a/29801077/6879709

Answer (score 0):

sudo nano /etc/mongod.conf
Disable (# auth = true)

Answer (score 0):

Quick workaround will be to check by disable authorization .

```
sed -i -e 's/authorization: enabled/authorization: disabled/' /etc/mongod.conf
systemctl restart mongod.service
```